# How to deal with Count() warning in PHP7.2?

Tags: php-7.2

How can I resolve this warning in PHP7.2 ?

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

Just check variable before passing to count() ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Maybe you can add more details and for example some code so we can understand your context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check it for example by

```
if (is_array($variable) && count($variable) > 0) { ... }
```